# graphQL api requests stopped working suddenly

Tags: java, api, graphql

so I had some code that's been working for months but recently it's suddenly stopped. It makes a request to the Anilist api to get information about some anime.

```java
try {
            String query = getQuery();
            query = query.replace("\n", " ").replace("  ", " ");

            URL url = new URL("https://graphql.anilist.co");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(query.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.close();

            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");

            in.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            //return result
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println("exception TRIGGERED");
            System.out.println(exp.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

So I put in breakpoints and it seems to break at line after the comment "// read the response". I've tried the same request using the *Altair GraphQL Client* extension for google chrome and the suggested tool at https://anilist.co/graphiql and they both work, so the problem seems like it's with my code somehow, but I haven't updated my environment. I also have an instance of the code running on aws (it's part of a discord bot), and I know I haven't touched that since I put the bot up there.
If you're interested, one of the queries I know used to work is

```
{"query":"query { 
  Media (type: ANIME, search: "naruto") { 
    id
    idMal
    type
    description(asHtml:false)
    chapters
    format
    episodes
    source
    genres
    averageScore 
    popularity
    isAdult
    status
    nextAiringEpisode {
      episode
      airingAt
      timeUntilAiring
    }
    startDate {
      year
      month
      day
    }
    season
    title {
      english
      native
      romaji
    }
    coverImage{
      large
      medium
    }
    studios (isMain: true) {
      nodes {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}"}
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you receive an error message? What do you mean with saying "it breaks"?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. The request now returns a 403 error "Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://graphql.anilist.co". wikipedia says that usually means the request is valid but forbidden for some reason. 
To troubleshoot that, I've messed with the query to make sure it isn't valid (same error), and I didn't put any authentication into _Altair_ or https://anilist.co/graphiql